# join count from one table to select from another - mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I have a select query with a subquery in it on table a:

```
select UserName, Name, anniversaryDate, RegionCode 
from a where UserName in
(
    select Username from
    (
        select Username, max(timeUsed)
        from log_table where role='Cou'
        group by Username order by max(timeUsed) desc limit 10
    ) a
)
```

which works fine, now I have another table called b,
on that table I only have 3 columns:

UserName, PName and feedback

which have each UserName multiple times and I want to join to my first query the count of each UserName I got from the first query.

for eaxmple:

```
SELECT COUNT(UserName) FROM b where UserName='Admin' group by UserName
```

How do I join the results from the second query to the first one?

Tables:
log_table :
id - Int, AI, PK
Username - varchar
Action - Int
timeUsed - Datetime
role - varchat

a:
UserName - varchar, PK
Name - varchar
anniversaryDate - Datetime
RegionCode - Int

b:
UserName - varchar
PName - varchar
feedback - varchar

Comment: You should really use joins instead of nested selects. Please share your table structure, it will help us figure out the way to help you.

Comment: the thing is like that: I need to get the last 10 users that made an action on my app (the nested select), then to get the basic info about these users from table a (the main select), and then just to add them the count from table b

Comment: Okay, thanks for clearing that up. Sharing your table structures would help in reproducing the circumstances and providing samples, but you can have meta-answers this way too :)

Comment: I have added the necessary tables structures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your table structure the query below might add the necessary column you are looking for:

```
    select users.UserName, Name, anniversaryDate, RegionCode, 
        Coalesce(count(b.UserName),0) as cnt 
    from users 
        left outer join (select Username, max(timeUsed)
            from log_table where role='Cou'
            group by Username order by max(timeUsed) desc limit 10
        ) a using (UserName)
        left outer join fedbacks b on (a.UserName = b.userName)
        group by users.UserName;
```

Comment: it for some reason returns me cnt 0, although there are rows in the table b with the UserName from table a

Comment: role='Cou'? It's case sensitive.